# Codeigniter error message now?

Tags: c#, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with my codes I'm using codeigniter, I'm new to this framework so any help will be much appreciated, this is my problem:
Im trying to get a specific attributes in my database which I can use for updating.

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: last_name

Filename: views/edit_patient_view.php

Line Number: 11

then this is my controller:

```
   public function edit_patient($patientID){
       if($patientID=== null){
       return;
       redirect('home/view_patient');
       }
           $data["patient"] = $this->patient_manager->edit_patient($patientID);
            $this->load->view("edit_patient_view", $data);
}
```

this is my model:

```
public function edit_patient($patientID){
        $this->db->select('first_name', 'last_name');
        $this->db->from('patients');
        if (!is_null($patientID)) $this->db->where('patient_id', $patientID);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();    
}
```

this is my view:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Edit Patient</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
          for($i = 0; $i < count($patient); $i++){
         $patients = $patient[$i];
            echo "<h1>Editing Patient Information</h1>";
                echo "First name:".form_input($patients['first_name'])."<br/>";
  }
?>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: add code for view for last_name field

Comment: on line no 13 of this file views/edit_patient_view.php your array refers to 'last_name' which is not defined yet.

Comment: just check the name your accessing its $patient not $patient

Answer (score 0):

You store last name in 'patient'

```
$data["patient"] = $this->patient_manager->edit_patient($patientID);
```

but when you used it in view page you add one 's'

```
$patients['first_name']
```

Change it in controller page

```
$data["patients"] = $this->patient_manager->edit_patient($patientID);
```

Or change line number 11

```
$patients['first_name'] to $patient['first_name']
```

Comment: Thanks! the error is gone, but I just want to ask since I want to show the first name in the form_input because I want that feature for my update view. but I cant access it in the database because I want to get the specific attributes not getting all. Thank you in advance.

Comment: unknown variable index